# Is this proof of monotone convergence theorem circular?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm reading below result from Amann's *Analysis III*. The Google book link to the actual page is [here](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=i3FYIWIYu5QC&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q&f=false).

---

**3.4 Theorem (monotone convergence)** Suppose $\left(f_{j}\right)$ is an increasing sequence in $\mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}}+)$. Then
$$
\int_{X} \lim _{j} f_{j} d \mu=\lim _{j} \int_{X} f_{j} d \mu \quad \text { in } \overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+}
$$

**Proof**

- (i) Set $f:=\lim _{j} f_{j}$. By Proposition $1.11, f$ belongs to $\mathcal{L}_{0}\left(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+}\right)$, and $f_{j} \leq f$ for $j \in \mathbb{N}$. By Remark $3.3(\mathrm{~b})$, then, we have $\int f_{j} d \mu \leq \int f d \mu$ for $j \in \mathbb{N}$, and hence $\lim _{j} \int f_{j} d \mu \leq \int f d \mu$.
- (ii) Suppose $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}\left(X, \mu, \mathbb{R}^{+}\right)$ with $\varphi \leq f$. Take $\lambda>1$ and set $A_{j}:=\left[\lambda f_{j} \geq \varphi\right]$ for $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\left(A_{j}\right)$ is an increasing sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ with $\bigcup_{j} A_{j}=X$ and $\lambda f_{j} \geq \varphi \chi_{A_{j}}$. Moreover, $\varphi \chi_{A_{j}} \uparrow \varphi$, so
  $$
  \int_{X} \varphi d \mu=\lim _{j} \int_{X} \varphi \chi_{A_{j}} d \mu \leq \lambda \lim _{j} \int_{X} f_{j} d \mu.
  $$
  Taking the limit $\lambda \downarrow 1$ we get $\int_{X} \varphi d \mu \leq \lim _{j} \int_{X} f_{j} d \mu$ for every $\mu$-simple function $\varphi$ with $\varphi \leq f$. By Remark $3.3(\mathrm{f})$, it follows that $\int_{X} f d \mu \leq \lim _{j} \int_{X} f_{j} d \mu$, and we are done.

---

In part (ii), the author said $\varphi \chi_{A_{j}} \uparrow \varphi$ implies
$$
\int_{X} \varphi d \mu=\lim _{j} \int_{X} \varphi \chi_{A_{j}} d \mu
$$

It seems the author uses MCT to obtain above equality. As such,

> Could you confirm that this reasoning is circular?

Comment: I cannot verify that this is circular without knowing everything that came before this point.  In particular, was $\int_{X} \varphi d \mu=\lim _{j} \int_{X} \varphi \chi_{A_{j}} d \mu$ already proved for nonnegative simple functions $\varphi$?

Comment: @GEdgar The Google book link to the actual page is https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=i3FYIWIYu5QC&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q&f=false.

Comment: @GEdgar You are totally right! It's my bad. The proof said that $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}\left(X, \mu, \mathbb{R}^{+}\right)$, i.e., $\varphi$ is a simple function.

Comment: @Akira Yeah whwn you write it out, the equality is a consequence of continuity of measure from below, I.e. MCT in the special case of indicator functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual proof of the MCT uses the fact that the monotone limit of a sequence of nonnegative simple functions satisfies the limit-integral swaparoo property.  I believe this is what is being used to justify the claim

$$ \int_X \varphi \ d\mu = \lim_j\int_X \varphi\chi_{A_j} \ d\mu $$

and not the MCT.

So I do not believe the proof is circular.

If the book has not independently proved this fact for monotone limits of nonnegative simple functions, then I believe one can derive it without too much struggle from the definition of the integral w.r.t. $\mu$.